# Device won't boot - Shows g.co/ABH secutiry error

Tags: security, factory-reset, boot-loop, google, lg

Device is a pretty much new LG V30 from verizon, running android 8.

I have done pretty much nothing with the device yet. No root, no tinkering, nothing. I accidentally accepted the software update request it showed me today, which I didn't want. I shut the device down but every time I would turn it on it would start the update progress.

The only other option I had was booting into recovery, so I did that. I was presented with the following options:

[image: IMG:]

So I went with factory reset. After that the phone won't boot anymore, and all I see is this screen:

[image: IMG:]

What can I do now? I could use warranty, but is there anything I can do myself right now?

Again: No root. No unlocked bootloader. Nothing. I used LG's "require password on boot" feature though, which I assume is equal to android's full disk encryption. **(?)**

---

Edit: Just talked to LG. Since my phone has [very minor] physical damage on its back, the warranty stands void per LG. What can I do now?

I can't even access fastboot. It just puts me into recovery. What am I doing wrong and what do I need to flash, assuming I can make it into fastboot?

Comment: [Googling error] (https://support.google.com/android/answer/6185381?visit_id=1-636692181638229495-149233797&p=verified_boot&rd=1) suggests it's best to contact OEM. Best to do that given it's in warranty

Comment: I'd just love to understand why/how this happened. I assume it has something to do with the encryption but since I requested a full factory reset that should vanish, shouldn'it it?

Comment: Factory reset sets the encryption to default keys not remove it, if that's what you are implying

Comment: Default keys being what? Shouldn't there be no key by default? I mean, when I first got the new phone it wasn't encrypted at all. (?) At least it didn't ask for a password on boot..

Comment: By default phones of recent versions are encrypted. Password on boot is additional (optional) thing to ensure that phone can't be used for basic services lulls making /answering calls without entering password

Comment: Now that explains why the "whole encryption" only took 5 seconds. Thank you a lot for clearifying that. I guess I'll take it to verizon then and see what they say.

Comment: @beeshyamsI have edited the question and added new information. LG claims the warrenty is void so now I have to fix it myself. Never LG again. That's ridiculous.

Comment: That's sad. Hope you get useful help soon